# Handling Show More/Less text in React Native

Tags: html, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-render-html

I'm getting a response from a remote API in HTML format. The whole thing is not supposed to be shown unless you press ***Read More*** button
The response looks as follows:

```
"<p>A suspension concentrate (SC) formulation containing 450 g/litre of napropamide (41.4% w/w) for the control of annual grass and broad-leaved weeds in winter oilseed rape.</p>\r\n<p><strong>DIRECTIONS FOR USE</strong><br /> IMPORTANT: This information is approved as part of the product label. All instructions within this section must be read carefully in order to obtain safe and successful use of this product.</p>\r\n<p><strong>RESTRICTION/WARNINGS</strong><br /> Weed control may be reduced where the spray is mixed too deeply into the soil. <br />Do not treat crops adversely affected by poor soil, adverse weather or cultural conditions. <br />Avoid spray overlap, particularly on headlands. <br />It is important to ensure that the seedbed is free from clods and weeds, and in good tilth.<br /> Incorporation under wet conditions is not satisfactory. <br />AC650 can be used on a wide range of soils but should not be applied to Sands (ADAS &rsquo;85 system)
...
```

I render it using `react-native-render-html` library which unfortunately does not have `numberOfLines` prop.

I tried a solution suggested on Github that involves adding custom renderer that substitutes all the `<p>` tags with react native `<Text>` tag which has numberOfLines props that I need:

```
<HTML
   html={`<p>${description}</p>`}
   renderers={{p: (_, children) => <Text numberOfLines={5}>{children}</Text>}}
/>
```

It worked but the problem is that I have several `<p>` tags inside my `description` variable and it shows all of them shortened to whatever number of lines I entered instead of shortening the whole article. So I figured that I must use a unique tag to wrap the whole HTML content and then apply the same logic

```
<HTML
  html={`<section>${description}</section>`}
  renderers={{section: (_, children) => <Text>{children}</Text>}}
/>
```

Again, the solution worked but it messed up the content inside. Line breaks were not applied, etc.

After a few more Google searches up stumbled upon a 3rd party library called `react-native-read-more-text` 
I understand that it only works with content inside `<Text>` tag so once again I wrapped by `<Text>` using template string

```
<ReadMore
  numberOfLines={10}
  renderTruncatedFooter={renderTruncatedFooter}
  renderRevealedFooter={renderRevealedFooter}>
    <HTML
    html={`<Text>${description}</Text>`}
    />
</ReadMore>
```

This time I received an error:

[image]

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 4):

This is now supported by react-native-render-html

```
import HTML from 'react-native-render-html'; // V6.3.4

const defaultTextProps = {
    numberOfLines: 10,
  };

  return (
    <HTML
      source={{ html: text }}
      defaultTextProps={defaultTextProps}
    />
  );
```

[Github Issue](https://github.com/meliorence/react-native-render-html/issues/94#issuecomment-761608657)

I hope this helps. I would be interested to know what you went with in the end as I am currently solving a similar use case.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would rather be not to mess-up with react-native-render-html, and instead do the following:

- wrap your HTML content inside a container which height approximates 5 lines;
- this container has a fading effect towards its bottom (typical in user-review platforms such as Goodreads);
- at the bottom of this container, a "read more" button can be pressed to expand the container height to fit the html content height.

If however you need *one tag renderer* in peculiar to implement such feature, you should take a look at this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69200348/2779871